# SQL Server Point Constructor or version of ST_Point(x,y)?

Tags: sql-server, spatial

PostGIS provides two point-constructors

- [`ST_MakePoint(x,y,[z,[m]])`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html)
- [`ST_Point(x,y)`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Point.html)or the compliant version that does not support 3DZ or 4D

MySQL supports [`Point(x,y)`](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/213813/2639)

**In SQL Server, Is there anyway to construct a point from two numeric inputs or reals without going from text first?**

I do not see a constructor that takes numbers 
in the docs on [*"Create, Construct, and Query geometry Instances"*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/create-construct-and-query-geometry-instances).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## SQL Server 2012+

Yes, it's not listed there though. You'll find [it documented on the docs of `geography::Point(x,y,srsid)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geography/point-geography-data-type)

> The following example uses Point() to create a geography instance.
>
> ```
> geography::Point(47.65100, -122.34900, 4326)
> ```

Microsoft calls it an "Extended Static Geography Methods"

It's documented in the [SqlGeography Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeography.aspx) and the Geometry constructor in the [SqlGeometry Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.types.sqlgeometry.aspx)